# How does one define seasonality (segments and knots) of predictors in stR::STR()?

Tags: r, string, time-series

stR package is based on [Hyndman and Dokumentov 2015](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/wp13-15.pdf) and contains an `STR()` function to which you may provide a description of topology of the seasonality you deal with, which is defined by a list of segments and a list of seasonal knots for each predictor you use (including trend). You may also provide a list of time knots. There is a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stR/vignettes/stRvignette.html) that is supposed to explain everything via examples, but neither the vignette nor the paper explains what these knots (time and seasonal) and segments are, and I failed to deduce that from the vignette, even though it's quite extensive. So, what are these things? What would they be for a simple model with, say, daily data and only trend + weekday/weekend seasonality?
Full disclosure - I haven't looked at the source code yet, but I doubt it would make things more clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use piecewise linear regression splines. The trend knots are where the trend changes direction. A seasonal knot is where the seasonal component changes direction. The segments are the linear pieces.

The package uses an automated algorithm for selecting the fitted functions. So using the defaults (not specifying any knots or segments) should give you a good fit.